# In shopping cart frameworks, what is the "model" field?

Tags: php, opencart

I've started to study OpenCart.

When I edit a product, there is a field for `model`, which must not be blank. I know lots of other e-commerce programs that also have a `model` attribute.

Can somebody tell me what this `model` field is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the field "product model" is the product number the shop owner uses to identify the exact product. Normally, in the shop systems I know, it does not need to be unique nor is it a required field (as the shop identifies a product by its ID not its model number)

Answer (score 1):

`model` would be the model-number of the product you are looking at. Basically a unique identifier to the product. Something to ensure that there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using opencart. MODEL is the manufacturers model number.

$product_info['model'] is where the model is found for altering the theme